# Could someone explain how to use the UpdateManager in TideSDK 1.3.1 Beta?

Tags: javascript, html, tidesdk

I was wondering if there was anyone online who would be willing to talk me through deployment and application updates in TideSDK 1.3.1?

The background is that I would like to build a HTML5 application wrapped in a desktop client, for deployment on Windows and Mac. The resulting application needs to have a simple installer and a mechanism for receiving updates either through the internet, or using an update installer if internet isn't available.

Are these features currently supported in TideSDK 1.3.1? And if so is there any documentation regarding the update process? I've looked through the API docs and have found reference to an UpdateManager, but have been unable to find examples of usage.

Rich

Answer (score 1):

TideSDK-1.3.1-beta currently contains legacy code for updates that is currently being refactored. As such, this is going through a transition presently. You will see us blog on our progress with this shortly. This piece of the SDK is critical and we understand its importance for app deployments.

We are currently working to provide better, more flexible installers that will be revealed to our users and the community as soon as we have this all together and tested. The refactoring and core improvements are modularizing the build and update code, giving us a much stronger foundation in the core to build upon. Application update and build services will use this new code. We will be making announcements on this important functionality. What we are doing will make everything easy and complete for everyone.

Comment: Thanks for the response @fairwinds. Is there anything in the current release that can be leveraged in terms of network updating, even if it's soon to be replaced?

Comment: TideSDK-1.3.2-beta is on its way in and the legacy update cruft is on its way out. TideSDK-1.3.2-beta will bring a series of updates, additional code refactoring and bug fixes. You will find new network build and update modules landing in the upcoming TideSDK-1.4.0. We are moving along at very good speed our path to this important release.