# Tidesdk Ti.UpdateManage

Tags: macos, tidesdk

anyone know what's Ti.UpdateManage module in TideSDK ?

I create a software with TideSDK framework and now I need to implement a system to upgrade the version of my software. I need to do alter table of DB (preserve data) and change others css style.

Thaks

Answer (score 0):

It was originally anticipated the update module would be reconstructed and work with a service. TideSDK was only in ever in beta so this remains uncompleted. Your best bet is to consider migrating to the commercial solution TideKit (tidekit.com) when it is available that will provide an update service. TideKit will also prevent your sources from being exposed to your users among other benefits.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746181/could-someone-explain-how-to-use-the-updatemanager-in-tidesdk-1-3-1-beta